# Get rows from two tables

Tags: sql

I am coding accounting system.
Here I am facing a problem as described below.

I have two sql table which records information about SALE and RECEIPT respectively.

For sale table

```
VoucherType     VoucherNo       CreditParty     CreditAmount
Sales           1               3               5000
Sales           2               5               10000
```

For receipt table

```
Vouchertype     VoucherNo       Amount          OppVoucherType       OppVoucherNo
Receipt         1               3000            Sales                1
```

Now you can see, receipt table contains information about which sales voucher has been paid.
For example, here I have sold 5000 amount of goods to party no 3 with Sales voucher 1.
For this, party no 3 has paid me only 3000 of amount agains sales bill of 5000.
In receipt table, I received 3000 of amount from party 3 in first receipt.

Now, party 3 still needs to give me 2000 of amount and party 5 still needs to pay me 10000 amount because there is no receipt for party no 5.

Now what i want is display, SALESVOUCHERNO and REMAINING AMOUNT TO PAY for each party from above data.

In short, I need data of each party which still needs to pay me the remaining amount.

Can you help me?

I tried with following query with unexpected results

```
Select v1.voucherno,v1.creditamount-v2.amount from Sales v1
inner join Receipt v2 on v1.vouchertype=v2.oppvouchertype
inner join Receipt v3 on v1.voucherno=v3.oppvoucherno
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` like so:

```
Select 
  v1.voucherno,
  v1.creditamount,
  v1.creditamount - IFNULL(v2.totalamount, 0) AS "REMAINING AMOUNT TO PAY"
from Sales v1
LEFT join
(
  SELECT oppvoucherno, OppVoucherType, SUM(amount) totalamount
  FROM Receipt
  GROUP BY voucherno, OppVoucherType
) v2  on v1.vouchertype = v2.oppvouchertype
                     AND v1.voucherno = v2.oppvoucherno;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21b17/1)

This will give you:

```
| VOUCHERNO | CREDITAMOUNT | REMAINING AMOUNT TO PAY |
------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         5000 |                    2000 |
|         2 |        10000 |                   10000 |
```

`LEFT JOIN` will include the unmatched rows from the `Receipt` table, which are those parities that had no receipts. Then use `IFNULL` to get zeros instead of `NULL`.

Suppose that there was a new entry to the second table, like:

```
('Receipt', 1, 1000, 'Sales', 1)
```

Then the query will handle that, and it will give you:

```
| VOUCHERNO | CREDITAMOUNT | REMAINING AMOUNT TO PAY |
------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         5000 |                    1000 |
|         2 |        10000 |                   10000 |
```

Comment: This wont help, what if I make a second receipt entry of remaining 2000 amount? For this, I need to calculate sum of all the receipt amount against the sales amount. And this is creating the problem.

Comment: OK i didnt say but obviously there will be second receipt entry for the remaining amount of any party. So i asked.

Comment: @HemalRathod - OK, Sorry I missed that. See my edit. It should work fine now. Test it and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select v1.voucherno,v1.creditamount-v2.amount from Sales v1
inner join Receipt v2 on v1.vouchertype=v2.oppvouchertype and v1.voucherno=v2.oppvoucherno
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
select s.VoucherNo as SALESVOUCHERNO,
case  when s.VoucherNo=r.VoucherNo then abs(s.CreditAmount-r.Amount)
else s.CreditAmount   
end
from sale s left outer join receipt r
on s.VoucherNo=r.VoucherNo;
```

[fiddle_demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/778f0/11)

Comment: @Hemal Rathod can you check my answer if this helps you